# Restarting server with bat file

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, batch-file

I'm trying to make a simple `bat` file that restarts a server. It looks like this:

```
shutdown -r -f -t 60
```

But all it does is loop inside the `cmd` window, printing the command > new line > priting the command. Over and over.

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> only opens up the menu on the machine where I RDP in from and not on the server itself.

Comment: What is the .bat file called? It's not shutdown.bat, is it? Also, Ctrl-Alt-End is the Ctrl-Alt-Delete in a RDP session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your batch file called `shutdown.bat`? If so, the script won't call system restart, the name causes the script to loop.

Try to rename your batch file to something else, or, as a good geek, move to PowerShell. If you decide to switch, you'll need the [`Restart-Computer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd315301.aspx) command.

Comment: Or be explicit: `shutdown.EXE -r -f -t 60`